# How to infer C# property name from Properties Tab, and how to manipulate them?

Tags: c#, properties

When I'm playing around with C# controls and their properties, I find no clue how to access or manipulate the properties by looking at the Properties Tab.  Is the Properties interface designed to indicate a way of accessing and assigning the properties, or should I rather look up documentations instead?

For example, when changing the back color of a window, the Properties Tab shows BackColor under Appearance, and has options as follows.
I thought the interface would be similar to one of the followings:

1. `this.Appearance.BackColor = 'ActiveCaption'`
2. `this.BackColor = 'ActiveCaption'`
3. `this.BackColor = System.ActiveCaption`

But the actual grammer is the following.  I can't find it by pressing F1 when focusing on the property, but I find it by searching ActiveCaption in Google.
Is there a better way of looking up related documentations?

```
this.BackColor = SystemColors.ActiveBorder;
```

[BackColor property list of a winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwNQK.png)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to find documentation for the properties assignable from the Properties window?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for an easier way of finding related documentations, or infer the grammar from the Properties tab by its structure, if it is designed so.

Comment: What do you mean by "infer the grammar"? If you change a property, you can see the accompanying code change in the `.Designer.cs` file.

Comment: Actually I'm new to C#, and am trying to find patterns to help me coding.  Looking up the .Designer.cs sure will help me learn, thanks! And may I ask is there a better way of searching for docs related to properties and controls?

Comment: Just Google "msdn winforms $controltype $propertyname", so for example "msdn winforms form backcolor". That'll take you straight to the documentation. Even though MSDN has been renamed to Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Get it, that will help!   I thought the doc may pop up or show somewhere in the IDE, but this is OK to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use F12 key to go to assembly info about classes to see the list of properties and their required values. Let say you are creating a Winform and you are on its designer adding controls or just editing properties just go to its cs file using F7 key you will see code like this just for sample.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then press F12 key when cursor on Form class you will get assembly details about the class like below.

[image]

You can see all properties and their required values rest you can google around your self and will get enough information.

Comment: Thanks! That's a convenient source of info inside the programming environment!

Answer (score 0):

The properties tab basically shows the properties of an object based on reflection and attributes. So basically it is implemented like

1. determine all properties of the selected element by refelection
2. an entry is added to the properties tab for each property whereas each entry will provide a property editor based on the property type
3. runtime code is generated based on the properties tab settings

So in your example the property BackColor is displayed with a *color picker* (a simple list box as shown in your linked picture) because the property is of type `System.Drawing.Color`. The properties tab implementation knows this type and displays the editor accordingly.

> How to infer C# property name from Properties Tab

this.{PropertyNameAsDispalyedInPropertiesTab} = {ValueAsDispalyedInPropertiesTab}

Comment: The left side of the assignment is clear to me, however in order to write the right side correctly, you not only need to know the value, but also the class it belongs to, which is unknown to me in the IDE, and I need searching to find out, that ActiveBorder belongs to SystemColors.  What about other properties, is it shown anywhere?